# Set Emacs defaut font face per-buffer/mode

Tags: emacs, fonts, themes, emacs-faces, font-lock

How do you change the default face which Emacs uses to style text on a per-mode basis?

For example, say that I am already happy with the face customizations that I have, which include a default fixed-width font. However, in one particular mode (`markdown-mode.el`, say), I want the default font to be variable-width.

It is easy to style headers, links etc. uniquely for markdown-mode: simply place the cursor over the styled text and `M-x describe-face`, then click the link to customize it.

However, the default face is the face used if no other face is specified, so it is not specific to markdown-mode and if modified will affect all other modes.

What magic can I put in the `markdown-mode-hook` to set the default face for buffers using this mode?

Comment: If there is a some variable that controls the default faces then you can localized it for the current buffer only in a hook that getting called while opening a file w/ markdown.

Comment: The question is asked in a general way, then a specific example is made and answers revolve around this specific example. If you really need to "**Set Emacs defaut font face per-mode**", see [Using a different font for each major mode - Emacs Stack Exchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/using-a-different-font-for-each-major-mode/3042#3042)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook (lambda () (variable-pitch-mode t))
```

You can then customize the `variable-pitch` face, and the other faces in the buffer will inherit from this instead of the default face.

Read the docs for `buffer-face-mode` for more customization details.  (BufFace is also used for `text-scale-increase` and `text-scale-decrease`... very useful.)

Comment: To my understanding this requires Emacs 23, can't find neither `variable-pitch-mode` nor `buffer-face-mode` in Emacs 22.

Comment: Wow, people still use Emacs 22?

Comment: Thanks, does the trick.

However, when a buffer uses variable-pitch fonts scrolling becomes so paaainfully slow that it's unusable. But this is probably just a bug.

Answer (score 6):

I have to give a partial answer because this is too complicated to figure out on the spot and I already blew my time budget.

Face is a frame property.  A frame can display multiple buffers at the same time.  Mode is a buffer property.  You ask how to vary the face on a per-mode basis.  Combining all this, it seems that the question cannot not have a single fully-correct answer.

You can approximate the desired answer if you assume that a given frame will never display more than one buffer.  You can actually accomplish that with something like this, but modified to use special-display-regexps and a set of regexps that match your markdown-mode buffer names.

```
(append special-display-buffer-names
        '("*VC-log*"
          "*Help*"
          ("*Completions*" 
           (height . 25)
           (font . "8x13"))))
```

However, this is probably not what you want.  Your question seems to imply changing the face properties of a single frame.

Again assuming that a frame will never display more than one buffer at a time, you can try advising switch-to-buffer.  But that might not be sufficiently low level and it might be too slow.  (untested)

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after switch-to-buffer activate compile)
  "change the frame's default face after switch-to-buffer"
  (doSomethingToChangePropertiesOfDefaultFace))
```

And now for my actual (incomplete) answer...

A better, albeit more complicated, approach would instruct markdown-mode to use a new face for all regions that are not already assigned one of the built-in faces.  You can create a new face with copy-face and give it interesting properties with set-face-*.

Modify markdown-mode's font-lock-defaults to override the default font-lock-fontify-region-function as described in the comment block near line 946 of font-lock.el that begins, "Fontification functions".  You can probably use a very slightly modified font-lock-default-fontify-region that does just one extra step immediately after it does:

```
  (unless font-lock-keywords-only
    (font-lock-fontify-syntactically-region beg end loudly))
```

The extra step parses the region similar to what font-lock-fontify-syntactically-region does, breaking the region into "interesting" sub-regions.  But this time you find sub-regions that have the default face and you put-text-property those sub-regions to the new face that you previously created.

In all this feels like it should be only a couple lines of elisp in your .emacs file, plus make a copy of font-lock-default-fontify-region that has only a minor diff from the original (call one new function), plus make a copy of font-lock-fontify-syntactically-region and modify it to do your bidding (the most difficult part).

Actually, if you "after" advise font-lock-fontify-syntactically-region then you probably don't even need to modify font-lock-defaults or font-lock-default-fontify-region.

Comment: Names and line numbers speak to GNU emacs 22.3.1.

Comment: Or just get a recent version of emacs and use buffer-face-mode.

Comment: Cool.  But I'll probably wait until emacs 23 actually ships before updating to it.

Answer (score 5):

The `variable-pitch`-mode is awesome. I found out about it through this thread. But it can be made even more awesome:

```
(dolist (hook '(erc-mode-hook
        LaTeX-mode-hook
        org-mode-hook
        edit-server-start-hook
        markdown-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook (lambda () (variable-pitch-mode t))))
```

Just add whatever mode you want sans-serif fonts in to the list.

Comment: What the code above does is to enable `variable-pitch-mode` for all the modes enumerated in all the lines except the last.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon `(variable-pitch-mode t)`

Answer (score 5):

There is a block of code which I find very convenient, from EmacsWiki. The advantage of this is that you can set not only font face, but conveniently configure `:height`, `:width` etc as well

```
;; Use variable width font faces in current buffer
(defun my-buffer-face-mode-variable ()
  "Set font to a variable width (proportional) fonts in current buffer"
  (interactive)
  (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "DejaVu Sans" :height 100 :width semi-condensed))
  (buffer-face-mode))
;; Use monospaced font faces in current buffer
(defun my-buffer-face-mode-fixed ()
  "Sets a fixed width (monospace) font in current buffer"
  (interactive)
  (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Consolas" :height 100))
  (buffer-face-mode))
;; Set default font faces for Info and ERC modes
(add-hook 'erc-mode-hook 'my-buffer-face-mode-variable)
(add-hook 'Info-mode-hook 'my-buffer-face-mode-variable)
```

Combined with `load-theme-buffer-local` package, you can even specify the color theme for the buffer easily:

```
(defun my-buffer-face-mode-variable ()
  "Set font to a variable width (proportional) fonts in current buffer"
  (interactive)
  (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "DejaVu Sans" :height 100 :width semi-condensed))
  (buffer-face-mode)
  (load-theme-buffer-local 'leuven (current-buffer)))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually straightforward even for emacs version 22.3.1…

Just try the following:

```
(progn 
  (set-buffer "your buffer name here")
  (overlay-put (make-overlay 0 (buffer-size)) 'face 'your-face))
```

Comment: you could also find a definition of a function that easily changes the font of a buffer at http://junis.orgfree.com/SetBufferFont.el

Comment: overlays are not good , because they are slow. they are good only if you do not have too many in the same time...