# How do I set Org Mode Agenda default formatting in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, font-lock

I want the Org Mode Agenda to have very different formatting to the rest of Emacs. How can I make this happen every time the Agenda is generated?

(N.b. this is not the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534307/set-emacs-defaut-font-face-per-buffer-mode) because Org Mode specifies different faces depending on how near a deadline is, and other information that is not given in the Agenda buffer.)

Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be very helpful to understand what you mean by "very different formatting." Baring that...

Theoretically, you should be able to either achieve what you seek using either `M-x customize-apropos org-agenda`, and/or by setting the proper org-agenda variables in your emacs config. You might even consider tying a number of functions/actions together in a custom function that you can use to create/modify the agenda buffer, or you might modify the `org-agenda-hook` to automatically perform the actions that you require.

It does sound like you are able to modify the buffer to appear the way you want it, the trick at this point, if I understand you correctly is to figure out how to automate this process.

Additionally, consider the following variables and `org-agenda` specific configurations I use.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c o a a") 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c o a l") 'org-agenda-list)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c o a t") 'org-todo-list)
(setq org-agenda-include-all-todo nil)
(setq org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
(setq org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done t)
(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
(setq org-agenda-columns-add-appointments-to-effort-sum t)
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands nil)
(setq org-agenda-default-appointment-duration 60)
(setq org-agenda-mouse-1-follows-link t)
(setq org-agenda-skip-unavailable-files t)
(setq org-agenda-use-time-grid nil)
```

I hope this helps.