# `variable-pitch` for org-mode, fixed-pitch for tables?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I found out about `variable-pitch-mode` [through a thread here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534307/set-emacs-defaut-font-face-per-buffer-mode), and it's very handy when writing in `org-mode`, easier on the eyes and everything. But using tables in org is close to worthless when using proportional fonts. And being able to use tables is one of the strengths with `org-mode` `:-(`

Is there any way to have proportional fonts for text, headings etc. but a monospace font for tables in `org-mode`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See if this works,

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-table nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
```

You may use <kbd>C-u C-x =</kbd> to see which face is in effect at a particular point.

Comment: Awesome! Works just like I want it :)

Comment: How did you find out that the table was 'org-table ?
I'd like to use this solution on the output of the SQL buffer

Comment: @EoghanM: If "C-u C-x =" didn't give the name of "face" or "font-lock-face", then the face in effect would be "default", by default.  The above method only applies when the buffer is highlighted in font-lock-mode or tagged otherwise in different faces.

Comment: For some reason, although running `describe-face` tells me that the font should be inheriting from ‘fixed-pitch (or just ‘default in my case), the displayed font is still ‘variable-pitch…

Comment: Never mind seems to be `buffer-local-theme` package causing the bug.

Comment: Follow-up question: how can I make this also affect links inside tables?

Answer (score 12):

This code will make tables and ascii art and source code blocks to be displayed in monospace font, while preserving other font attributes for tables (such as color blue) and so on. Code is based on the other answer, the only difference is preservation.

```
(defun my-adjoin-to-list-or-symbol (element list-or-symbol)
  (let ((list (if (not (listp list-or-symbol))
                  (list list-or-symbol)
                list-or-symbol)))
    (require 'cl-lib)
    (cl-adjoin element list)))

(eval-after-load "org"
  '(mapc
    (lambda (face)
      (set-face-attribute
       face nil
       :inherit
       (my-adjoin-to-list-or-symbol
        'fixed-pitch
        (face-attribute face :inherit))))
    (list 'org-code 'org-block 'org-table 'org-block-background)))
```

If you'd like to learn how this works and how to apply this to other situations (such as Info mode), read [my post on the subject](http://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/monospace-font-in-tables-and-source-code-blocks-in-org-mode-proportional-font-in-other-parts/)

Comment: For some reason, although running `describe-face` tells me that the font should be inheriting from ‘fixed-pitch (or just ‘default in my case), the displayed font is still ‘variable-pitch…

Comment: Never mind seems to be `buffer-local-theme` package causing the bug.