# Emacs: Multiple fonts in a single buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use org-mode daily for all sorts of things, and I like variable-width fonts for reading text which makes up the majority of my files.  But for tables to be correctly aligned, a fixed-width font it necessary.  Is it possible to configure emacs to show org-mode tables in a fixed-with font and the rest of the buffer in a variable-width font?

I understand the typical question is not: *"Is X possible in emacs?"* but rather *"How do I do X in emacs?"* so I'm optimistic, but haven't found an answer on Google or SO yet...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3758139/16240

Comment: Concerning tables, maybe something analogous to nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/ can also work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`variable-pitch\` for org-mode, fixed-pitch for tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758139/variable-pitch-for-org-mode-fixed-pitch-for-tables)

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple fonts in a buffer (C-h C-a to see an example).

You can customize the font family of any face in emacs, so you can have variable and fixed width sizes fonts.

Then you can use `font-lock-add-keywords` (for example) in `org-mode-hook` to instruct font-lock to use a face with fixed width the regular expression that matches rows of a table (I think it would be something like `"\s*|.*"`, but maybe I am oversimplifying)

Comment: This is great.  For the specific problem I was having (fixed-width in org-tables) the answer linked to by huaiyuan is simpler.  But this answer is more widely applicable and useful in other situations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a more current solution you can check out [mixed-pitch](https://gitlab.com/jabranham/mixed-pitch) mode. It takes care of adjusting fonts not only tables and src-blocks in org-mode but also takes care of fonts in other text modes as well (LaTeX mode, for example).