# setting font-lock-face to different values for different major-modes

Tags: emacs, config, mode, font-lock

I am trying to set for example `font-lock-comment-face` to `Blue` for `csharp-mode` and for `c++-mode` to `Red` is this possible or not?

Right now im using:

```
(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil :foreground "#57a64a")
(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-keyword-face nil :foreground "#569cd6")
```

but this sets the value globally and not only for the mode.

Forgot to add the version im using: GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2014-10-24 on LEG570
on Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! Thank you, I've thought it's not possible, but then i've found this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FacesPerBuffer

Just look at the example from wiki, seems like exactly what you need:

```
 (make-face 'php-comment-face)
 (set-face-foreground 'php-comment-face "LightGrey")
 (add-hook 'php-mode-hook 
       (lambda ()
        ;; ...
        (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-comment-face)
             'php-comment-face)
        ;; ...
```

Thanks to this question from related: [Set Emacs defaut font face per-buffer/mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534307/set-emacs-defaut-font-face-per-buffer-mode)

### UPD

to win the cc-mode bindings, you should put the `(add-hook csharp-mode-hook ...` after `(add-hook c-mode-hook ...`, like this:

```
(make-face 'c-comment-face)
(set-face-foreground 'c-comment-face "Red")

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
       (lambda ()
        ;; ...
        (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-comment-face)
             'c-comment-face)))


(make-face 'cs-comment-face)
(set-face-foreground 'cs-comment-face "Blue")

(add-hook 'csharp-mode-hook
       (lambda ()
        ;; ...
        (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-comment-face)
             'cs-comment-face)))
```

If you have hook codes in separate files, you should load csharp-mode settings after c-mode. Don't forget to `(remove-hook ...` to try this out.

Comment: doesnt seem to work. ive used this line (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-comment-face) 'c-comment-face) in my c-mode-hook but in the csharp file the comments were also red.

Comment: as for me, everything works fine. I bet this is because 
"It’s based on cc-mode"
(https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode)

Comment: i have a splitted window, on one side the c file and on the other side a csharp file both opend at the same time. the mode loaded recently sets the color for the comment

Comment: hm, may be i do not understand what you need.. look at this pic, is this look like what you want to get? http://oi59.tinypic.com/xglfme.jpg

Comment: yea exactly that left side and right side with different colors for lets say a comment

Comment: so, this what i've got after evaluated the code from scratch buffer in that order, as i said earlier. May be you should clean hooks or simply restart emacs and re-eval this code

Comment: i dont know why it didnt work the first time but now it works cheers :)